# PHPExcel converting to utf8 from ISO characters

Tags: phpexcel

I'm having trouble in getting the correct characters from my .xls file.
 Based on what I found on the internet, it seems that it has something to do with  the encoding or its something about html that cant be read through PHPexcel. It says that for PHPExcel to read the file it has to be utf-8. Can you give me hints on how to get the correct encoding or getting to read it by utf-8?

Here's my code:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $pathgalleriadeclare = "C:\Users\Desktop\sample.xls";


try {


    $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($pathgalleriadeclare);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
    $objReader->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
    utf8_encode($objReader);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($pathgalleriadeclare);

} catch(Exception $e){

    die('Error loading file "' .pathinfo($pathgalleriadeclare, PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());


}


$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

for ($row = 7; $row <= $highRow; $row++){

    //REPORT
    $value = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();

    echo $value ;
    echo "<br />";

}


$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objPHPExcel);
exit();
```

Here's a sample output:
[image]

Comment: So what type of file is this?

Comment: @MarkBaker  all I know that this is a .xls file that has been generated from a 3rd party software.

Comment: @MarkBaker after checking multiple times for the file. It's a html file

Comment: The HTML Reader won't convert any values from its charset, an you can't simply use utf8_encode() on the reader or the spreadsheet or worksheet objects, or even on the cell objects, you'll have to do this by hand on a cell by cell basis against the cell values